# Junit 4 checkbox in jmeter getting cleared when running test

Tags: junit, jmeter

I wrote a junit 4 test case. The test is using selenium web driver. It works fine when running from eclipse. I then copied the exported jar file to jmeter lib/junit folder. The class name and test name is populating when I am selecting **Search for Junit 4 annotations** checkbox. You can find this from screenshot.

[image]

But as soon as I start load test by clicking the green play button, the **Search for Junit 4 annotations** checkbox gets cleared and thereby no class and test name is passed to the load test. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

My Class was not extending TestCase.

import junit.framework.TestCase;

Then extend the class to TestCase. This resolved this issue.